# Start activity on the Background

Tags: android, android-activity, react-native, push-notification

I am developing a webrtc Android react native app, which allows users to make/receive calls. When the app is killed, the user receives a silent notification (incoming call) that starts the app. I am fine with this behaviour, I just want to start the activity on the background and only show to the user when is fully loaded.

I am using react-native-fcm, and this piece of code to start the app upon arrival of notification.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myAppName");
      if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
      }
    }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: It was stated above, can I start the activity on the background without showing it to the user ?

Comment: Is your loading time very long or something? When you request to start the Activity it will load immediately. You can make network requests before starting it and launching when all data is ready, but UI won't wait.

Comment: as soon as I call `startActivity(launchIntent);` the UI shows but the call isn't loaded yet to answer the call, so I want to start the activity in the Background and only show it when everything is ready. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html for creating a Service.